# Maintaining a reference to the facebox element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the facebox plugin in jQuery. I would like to maintain a pointer to it after I have triggered it, so that i can transform the elements in it, etc.

Here is what i want to do, but facebox() returns a nil.

I know i can call "#facebox .xxx", but that always makes me squeamish

```
//fb is a pointer to the facebox
fb  =$.facebox("facebox")
fb.find("textarea").text("custom text here")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fadebox depends on there being a single `#facebox` element in the page, you can use `#facebox` as your selector here without any issues here...the plugin doesn't leave much alternative, just do:

```
$("#facebox textarea").text("custom text here")
```